# Separate independent screen using X and Python

Tags: x11, python, pygame

I have a request for guidance/keywords to search on a problem that is new to me.

1. We are running a microscopy application on Ubuntu 20.04 and using Python.
2. We have two HDMI outputs on our GPU. One output is used for a standard screen, the other output is connected to a projector (micromirror device).
3. We are using the 2nd output to stream patterns of light onto some device. To do so, we are using pygame and open a window of appropriate size at particular "coordinates" corresponding to the location of the 2nd screen. This works fine.
4. The problem: Even though the pygame window covers the 2nd screen, we still have some interference from the OS. E.g., it may display the desktop background if the pygame window is not open, or users may accidentally draw a window to the 2nd screen (even if the mouse is locked to the 1st screen).

I have been told to look into X11 (and a separate server), but it is beyond my knowledge at the moment, and I am not quite sure what to look for. Ideally, I would have some mechanism to disable the 2nd output for the standard OS, and specify something in Python to direct the output to the 2nd screen. Could someone please point me into the right direction? Maybe there already is a guide out there I have not been able to find?

Any help is greatly appreciated.